# Perform Soft Keyboard keys press using Accessibility Service android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, accessibilityservice

Hi I am performing a click on EditText using Accessibility Service on screen and when that click is performed how do i perform clicks on Soft keyboard which is opened, is there any possible way to do so.

Let's assume I know the coordinates of alphabet 'A' in keyboard and I want to perform click on the same, how do I achieve the same using Accessibility Service in Android?

Comment: I'm also implementing similar functionality and I have to perform/dispatch key events from accessibility service, but I couldn't find any solutions for it.
Have you found any solution?

Comment: So what's the required functionality, do you have coordinates for the point which you want to press?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question a little wrong, I just needed to make a key event andI found a solution for my case.